# Screen capture inside the method onCreate not working in android

Tags: android

I am working in an android application and I want to capture the screen of current activity in the Overrided method onCreate(). The bitmap returns null when I wrote the code for capturing screen inside the Overrided method onCreate(). But when I call the same code in a button click in the same activity the bitmap returns the correct value. Please correct my code to return by bitmap in my ocCreate() method itself.

My code is :

```
View v1 = findViewById(R.id.printpreviewBaseScrollView);
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bmv = v1.getDrawingCache();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
View printlayout = findViewById(R.id.printpreviewBaseRelativeLayout);
        printlayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

        printlayout.measure(printlayout.getMeasuredWidth(),
                printlayout.getMeasuredHeight());

         printlayout.layout(0, 0, 700, 1755);



        Log.e("width", "" + printlayout.getMeasuredWidth());
        Log.e("hight", "" + printlayout.getMeasuredHeight());

        printlayout.buildDrawingCache(true);

        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(printlayout.getDrawingCache());
        printlayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false); // clear drawing cache
```

Answer (score 0):

You must do it later than onCreate.  During onCreate, your layout is measured and inflated but your UI is not yet created.  See the Activity life cycle documentation:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html

```
@Override
public void onStart(){
     View v1 = findViewById(R.id.printpreviewBaseScrollView);
     v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
     Bitmap bmv = v1.getDrawingCache();
}
```

I just copied and pasted your code. You should probably make v1 a class level variable, set it's reference in onCreate(), then get the bitmap in onStart().

Comment: Sorry, Still i am not getting the bitmap as null in onStart() and onResume() method. Is there any other method to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Create method called 
void screenshot(){
Your btimap code
}
Onactivity call 
screenshot();

Answer (score 0):

As the method 'onCreate()' suggests your activity will be created in this moment. So you can't take a screen capture at this point. Try your code in 'onResume()':

```
...
@Override
public void onResume(){
    View v1 = findViewById(R.id.printpreviewBaseScrollView);
    v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap bmv = v1.getDrawingCache();
}
...
```

Comment: Sorry, Still i am not getting the bitmap as null in onResume() method. Is there any other method to do this ?

Answer (score -1):

According to android's documation

> The **visible lifetime** of an activity happens between a call to
>   onStart() until a corresponding call to onStop(). During this time the user can see the activity on-screen, though it may not be in the foreground and interacting with the user.

[image]

As can be seen from the graph above, it is not in the **visible lifetime** when **onCreate()** is executed, and you cannot get the screenshot.

Move your code to **onResume()**, which should be in the **visible lifetime**.

Comment: Sorry, Still i am not getting the bitmap as null in onResume() method. Is there any other method to do this ?