# NullPointer when trying to progmatically capture screen

Tags: java, android, xml

Here is my code

```
    // create bitmap screen capture
    Bitmap bitmap;
    View v1 = (View)findViewById(R.id.text);
    View rootV = v1.getRootView();
    rootV.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    bitmap = rootV.getDrawingCache();
    rootV.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

the nullpointer occurs on `bitmap = rootV.getDrawingCache();`  and `R.id.text` is a textView in the layout

Comment: Is R.id.text in the same layout?

Comment: Can you post the layout? And the whole stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the answer here. Its because I was calling the method in the onCreate()

[Screen capture inside the method onCreate not working in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13173022/screen-capture-inside-the-method-oncreate-not-working-in-android?rq=1)